# checking if there a list of lists can unify with another list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

So i have two predicates the 1st is palavra_uni(Word,Var) in which Word is list of words like `[[d,a,y],[n,i,g,h,t]]` for example and Var is list that contains vars or constants like `[P1,P2,P3]` or `[d,P2,P3]`.

The purpose of the first predicate is to return true if any of the any list of words is unifiable with Var.

Example:

```
?- palavras_uni([[a, m, e, n, o], [a, t, o], [d, a, o], [d, i, a]],[P12,P13,P14]).
true.

?- palavras_uni([[d,a,y], [n,i,g,h,t]],[P12,a,P14]).
true.

?- palavras_uni([[d,a,y], [n,i,g,h,t]],[P12,P13]).
false.
```

Well the problem is that this predicate shows the unified variables instead of giving true.

Example:

```
?- palavras_uni([[a, m, e, n, o], [a, t, o], [d, a, o], [d, i, a]],[P12,P13,P14]).
P12 = a,
P13 = t,
P14 = o.

?- palavras_uni([[d,a,y], [n,i,g,h,t]],[P12,a,P14]).
P12 = d,
P14 = y.

?- palavras_uni([[d,a,y], [n,i,g,h,t]],[P12,P13]).
false.
```

As for my 2nd problem i have a predicate called espacos_uni(LS,LP) in which Ls is a list of lits containing variables for example `[[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [P13, P23, P33, P43, P53]]` and LP is list of list containing words just like before, for example `[[d,a,y],[n,i,g,h,t]]`.

The purpose of this predicate is to return true if any of the words is unifiable with any of the Vars

Example:

```
?- espacos_uni([[P11, P21, P31, P41, P51], [a, P23, P33, P43, P53]],[[a, m, e, n, o],[a, t, o], [d, a, o],[d, r, a, m, a], [m, a, e], [m, a, n, d, e], [s, e, d, e], [s, o, a, r]]).
true.
```

But instead of giving true this is giving false all the time and i cant understand why.

Program:

```
palavra_uni([P|_],E) :- P = E,!.

palavra_uni([P|R],E) :- P \= E,
                        palavra_uni(R,E).

espacos_uni([P|R],LP) :- palavra_uni(LP,P),
                         espacos_uni(R,LP).

espacos_uni([P|R],LP) :- \+ palavra_uni(LP,P),
                         espacos_uni(R,LP).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First part of your question:

That is the behavior of Prolog. If Prolog can prove your query, it will print out the satisfying assignment of the free variables in your query. So if you see variables being printed out, this is equivalent to `true`.

You can suppress the printing of variables by using `_` (anonymous variable):

```
?- palavras_uni([[a, m, e, n, o], [a, t, o], [d, a, o], [d, i, a]],[_,_,_]).
true.
```

As soon as you give the variables a name, you are signaling to Prolog that you are interested in their values.

### Second part of your question:

You have two rules for `espacos_uni`.

- The first says that `espacos_uni` is true if the first entry in the variable list unifies with any entry of the word list **and the remaining part of the variable list again satisfies `espacos_uni`**.
- The second says that `espacos_uni` is true if the first entry in the variable list does not unify with any entry in the word list and the remaining part of the variable list satisfies `espacos_uni`.

The second rule is fine. The problem is with the first rule: It will successfully find the matches, but then always go on looking for further matches, which eventually fails when the list becomes empty. You can fix this by removing the recursion in the first rule:

```
espacos_uni([P|_],LP) :- palavra_uni(LP,P).
```